# Angle between velocities: Elastic collision question in 3D

Tags: reference-frames, momentum, collision, scattering, protons

I have been given a scenario of a proton (particle 1) travelling with **u**1 = 3**î**+ 4**j**–6**k** and a Helium-3 nucleus (particle 2) travelling with **u**2= 3**î**+ 4**j**–2**k**. The two particles collide and the proton (particle 1) is *scattered elastically in the x-direction in the centre of mass frame*. Treating the two particles as if they were billiard balls, with masses m1= u and m2= 3u (where non-vector u is the atomic mass unit), I need to find

a.) the momenta of the two particles in the centre-of-mass frame *after* the collision and
 b.) the **angle** between the velocities after the collision in the C.o.M and Lab frames.

For a.) I obtained (3u)**k** and (–3u)**k** for the momenta of particles 1 & 2, respectively, but I do not know if this is correct.

I am *completely stuck* on b.) as I really do not know how to relate these momenta to finding a scattering angle, so I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Assuming $\vec{u}_i$ are the velocities of the particles, I don't agree with your momenta calculation. $\vec{p}_i=m\vec{v}_i$, so the momenta of the particles are $\vec{p}_1=3u\hat{i}+4u\hat{j}-6u\hat{k}$, $\vec{p}_2=9u\hat{i}+12u\hat{k}-6u\hat{k}$. If this is not the right interpretation, can you clarify?

Comment: @levitopher The velocity of the centre of mass in the lab frame is 3i+4j–3k if you divide the sum of the initial momenta by the total mass. This yields C.o.M frame initial velocities of –3k and k for (1) and (2) respectively? Then I used the fact that in the C.o.M frame, the initial momenta are always equal and opposite and that in the C.o.M frame, p'1= μ(u1–u2), where μ is the reduced mass. Where I think I might have gone wrong is the relative velocity I used was in the lab frame, when it should be the C.o.M frame?

Comment: Well, I did misunderstand your original question, so I agree with your CoM initial velocities now. I'll just point out that you haven't used either conservation of momentum or energy (since it's an elastic collision), so I think that's the next thing to do. And now that you're in the CoM frame, just do everything in that frame before switching back.